# SSIS-Cleaning up CSV

Tags: ssis

I've created something in SSIS to create  a csv file based upon 4 sql queries.  It uses an array of sorts and merges to give back (what appears to be) a csv in the correct format.  However, there are trailing commas in lines that aren't the length of the longest line.  The shortest line with data is only 1 column while the longest is about 46.  So the 1 column line has 45 commas to match the longest line.

This CSV file needs to be generated and sent to a 3rd party vendor on a regular basis.

How do I clean up the commas?  Is there a way to execute either VB or C# code inside of SSIS that it would traverse each line and clear out all the commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first: why do you need to remove the commas? A CSV represents (at its core) a single data set of presumably equivalent data. So that 1 column line and that 46 column line should be similar entities, and the 45 blank values are perfectly valid. If they aren't similar entities, why are they in the same CSV?

That having been said, to simply remove the commas, since you're implying you're comfortable with .Net, what you want is a [Script Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141752.aspx).

After your data flow to create the CSV, create a script task that:

1. Opens the generated CSV.
2. Reads in the lines in a loop.
3. Drops all the trailing commas.
4. Writes the line to string buffer.
5. Dumps the string buffer to a file at the end.

Alternatively you can create a batch file or executable that performs this same task and then use the [Execute Process task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141166.aspx) with your CSV as an argument.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me.  The reason I need to remove the commas is because this file will eventually get to a 3rd party vendor.  The format of the csv has to be in a way that they require it.  The extra 45 commas is techincally correct but in this case it will cause their process to fail.  Thank for how to do this.  I will attempt when I get back to my desk.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer.  It seems right in my mind.  Just haven't tried it yet.